# im getting error of program does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, generics, arraylist

I'm getting an error, "Program does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point."

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program<T>
    {
        List<T> a1 = new List<T>();
        public void AddData(T data1)
        {
            a1.Add(data1);
        }
        public void Insert(T arrayValue, int arrayPosition)
        {
            // var key = arrayPosition.ToInt();
            var key1 = arrayValue.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < a1.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == arrayPosition)
                {
                    a1.Add(arrayValue);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public void Delete(int arrayPosition)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a1.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == arrayPosition)
                {
                    a1.Remove(a1[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public void DisplayData()
        {
            foreach (T x in a1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
        }
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program<int> obj = new Program<int>();
            obj.AddData(123);
            obj.AddData(56);
            obj.AddData(34);
            obj.AddData(87);

            obj.DisplayData();
            obj.Insert(125, 3);
            obj.DisplayData();
            obj.Delete(2);
            obj.DisplayData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Crowcoder 
I'm getting an error, "Program does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point."

Comment: Tried using different class but didnt worked

Comment: Why on Earth is Program generic? I imagine it might be having trouble with that.

Comment: Sorry, I coudn't resist based on pre-edit question. Check out the related questions over there > on the right. This is a simple mistake you will only make once.

Answer (score 1):

Per Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0402) you cannot put your main function in a generic class. It's strange that this was reported as a warning, and the error was less helpful, but that is your problem.

Comment: I tried using another class but im failing to call the methods from this Program class. Please give me some tips

Comment: I can't help unless I know what problem you had calling the methods in another class from the Program class.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Int32> obj = new List<Int32>();
            obj.Add(123);
            obj.Add(56);
            obj.Add(34);
            obj.Add(87);

            foreach (Int32 value in obj)
                Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());

            obj.Insert(3, 125);

            foreach (Int32 value in obj)
                Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());

            obj.RemoveAt(2);

            foreach (Int32 value in obj)
                Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Defining a custom class to handle this tasks looked to me like an overkill. This code should reproduct what you were attempting to do without errors. Anyway, I suggest you to take a look at some basic C# tutorial.

Comment: I am learning c# generics so I need to know what was the error and how to overcome

Comment: Well first, you were trying to create a new instance of your program class within the entry point, which is not a good idea due to the fact that it already implements an entrypoint. Then you defined methods and parameters inside your program class to implement list functions which is absolutely unnecessary (no need to reinvent the wheel). In you Insert method you convert the index to string and you try to compare it to an integer with a straight equality.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the static void at the top of the Program class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `void` cannot be applied to a class.